# Mudar apache no Cpanel

Tags: laravel-5, php-7, cpanel

Fiz uma aplicação em laravel 5 e preciso subir para um servidor que não é meu, só tenho uma conta FTP para isso. O problema é q p servidor CPanel está configurado para PHP 5 e o laravel roda em PHP 7. A hospedagem citada acima está com EasyApache 3 e para ter o Software PHP Selector no CPanel precisa do EasyApache 4.
Minha dúvida é se eu mudar o EasyApache os sites que já estão hospedados lá e rodam em PHP 5 deixarão de funcionar? Se eu mudar para EasyApache 4 é possível fazer o downgrade depois??

Answer (score 0):

Boa Tarde
É possível instalar o PHP7 no EA3, contudo a atualização do servidor para as versões mais recentes do CPanel é recomendada, porem para tal é preciso verificar se a versão do CentOS instalada suporta tal atualização.

No caso de instalar o EA4, sim é possível escolher por conta qual PHP será utilizado, porém após instalado o EA4 não é possível utilizar mais o EA3.

Att,

Tiago Ceridorio